# SQL Repeat / Looping

Tags: sql

I'm trying to repeat / loop this SQL query for countless of times.

`UPDATE cq_eudemon SET damage_type='5'`

Comment: Why are you doing what you're doing? You need to supply more context as to what you're doing, why, what's happening and what you expect should be happening. There needs to be a question.

Comment: Why are you trying to repeat it? Give us some more details on what exactly is your problem.

Comment: Loop over what? You already set the value.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL or MS SQL?

Comment: do you want to update all record with damage_type = 5? or else? if Yes, your query has already done that

Answer (score 2):

No looping would be required in SQL.  You are defining a set or subset of the data then applying an action to it.  The SQL code you have written above will set all of the 'damage_type' columns for all rows in the table cq_eudemon to '5' all in that single statement.